# golang martini session.Set not setting any value

Tags: session, go, martini

There isn't much context with this because it really is a situation where something should work, but it just doesn't.

I am using the martini framework. In one handler I'm using this:

```
session.Set("deployed", "true")
r.Redirect("/myOtherURL", http.StatusSeeOther)
```

Whereby 'session' is the sessions.Session object passed through to the handler.
In the handler that loads myOtherURL, I'm using session.Get but nothing is being returned. I printed out all of the session content and the 'deployed' is not present.

What could be causing this problem? What could I possibly be missing out? I would give more context if I could but it really is as simple as this.

Comment: Can you post more of your code: the full handler for both the set & get operations, and the setup code for the cookie store, including any options (Secure, HttpOnly) you're setting.

Comment: @elithrar this is quite difficult because my functions are large. I have noticed that when going through path /modules in the URL, there is a second cookie/session produced. I can see it on the dev tools on google chrome. I'm guessing these separate sessions are the reason my variables aren't shared. Do you know why it would produce a second session? Is this heard of before? I don't do anything differently for this /modules route with respect to handlers/sessions, its the same as the others, but for some random reason it creates a new session.

Comment: Are you setting the path of the cookie? If not, it will default to the current path - e.g. `/modules`. If the other route is at the same level or above the cookie won't apply. You'll need to set `session.Options.Path` to a path that covers both - the easy choice is to set it to `/`.

Comment: @elithrar You are a life saver, marry me

Comment: Sadly (for both of us) I'm taken! I've added this as answer now that I'm at a desktop machine for posterity/other Gophers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to extend on my comment/help others in the future:

- When you set a cookie without an explicit `Path` value, the cookie takes on the current path.
- Cookies are only sent for that path and paths below - not above - e.g.

  1. Cookie set for `/modules` when you implicitly set it for the first time via `session.Set(val, key)`
  2. Cookie *is* sent for `/modules`, `/modules/all` and `/modules/detail/12`
  3. Cookie is *NOT* sent for `/about` or `/`

This can be fixed by explicitly setting the path:

```
var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret123"))

func main() {
    store.Options.Path = "/"
    ...
}
```

Be aware that you may not want to send a cookie for all routes (which is what `/` will do) - so use judgement.